# Windows File History does not backup iCloud drive folder

Tags: windows-10, backup, icloud, file-history

I am using **File History** for backing up my documents on a Windows-10 machine.
It back ups fine every file except those files/folders located in the iCloud Drive folder under `C:\Users\myName\iCloudDrive\`.

File History is set to include this folder. And no files/folders are set to exclude. The config xml files seems to resemble the GUI settings.

I also checked the Event Log, which shows no errors!

How can I backup the iCloud Drive folder using Windows File History?

Comment: See if this Microsoft Article helps you.   It talks about network folders (iCloud).   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-history-in-windows-5de0e203-ebae-05ab-db85-d5aa0a199255

Comment: Thank you @John for your comment. Unfortunately, this article does not help. I already set up File History on a network drive.

Comment: Network drives and folders synchronised with a cloud storage are two very different things. Since iCloud Drive has its own file history mechanism, it's possible that Windows implicitely exclude the folder from any backup (if so, there's probably a way to change this behavior, but I can't help). Also I can see a potential problem when backing up these folders: if sync-on-demand is enabled, any remote change of a file would trigger the local backup and hence the download of the file. Which makes the on-demand feature useless.